# Use 'COUNT(*) OVER() AS' in postgres while selecting items from a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgres-9.6

I am doing a selection on a table, but also need the count of the items. Apparently I have to use  window functions but can't get it work.

I am doing a simple select query and want to count how many entries are there, so something like:

```
SELECT * FROM "myTable"
COUNT(*) OVER() AS total
WHERE name='John Doe';
```

This is not working and I am getting the following error: `ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COUNT" LINE 2: COUNT(*) OVER(name) AS _total`
How do I use the window functions to count my entries in a table while doing a query? Am I way off base here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `COUNT(*)` is a column in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER() AS total
FROM "myTable" t
WHERE name = 'John Doe';
```

The `FROM` clause follows the `SELECT` clause and ends the definitions of the columns in the result set.